# Is this GRU learning good?

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, gru

[image]

Result seems to be a little out of "expected" values.
It's timeseries dataset.

Comment: The loss curves look good. Maybe use a different loss? (e.g. mean absolute error instead of mean squared error)

Comment: Will try, thanks.